# parent::method() - calling non static method

Tags: php, oop, parent

I don't understand the concept of calling a parent method in PHP.
The parent method is not static, yet it is called statically - normally PHP would throw an error/warning.

**Question is, is this a quirk from PHP, or is this how it should be in OOP?**

Taking the example from php.net:

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

> In PHP 5, calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT
>   level warning.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Question/answer with similar content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18738707/5542121

Comment: Another interesting one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11165429/5542121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you will look at the [definition of static method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods) you will see:

1. *Static methods are meant to be relevant to all the instances of a class rather than to any specific instance.* - indeed this method is relevant to all children of the parent class.
2. *A static method can be invoked even if no instances of the class exist yet.* - again, you never create an instance of the parent class to invoke the method.

So we can take this argument as an excuse for **PHP**. By the way, in **C++** it is done the same way.

But there are other languages, where it is done like you said. For example, in **JAVA**, the parent method called like `super.printMethod();`, in **C#**, it is done like `base.printMethod()`.

So in **PHP** it might be done for the parser simplicity, as they will need a specific edge case for such invocation `parent->printMethod()`.

Comment: Now I wonder what the scope/context will be in the parent method, but that is outside of the question I asked. Time for some experiments, if I only took the time...

Answer (score 2):

That notification means that you can't call a non-statically defined method as static, but the call you did inside the method is not a static call, but a call to the parent class.

So this call will throw the E_STRICT warning:

```
$b = new B;
$b::example();
```

but your example will not

Comment: Then why is not written like `parent->method()`  wouldn't that make more sense? Its confusing me.